# Clear btn in Text input is not working well in android devices

Tags: react-native

I've a btn that clears the text in input which works when the button is touched. But the problem is that the text previously inputted also appear when new text is inputted. How can I solve this problem?

Code:

```
<View style={styles.textInputStyle}>

    <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({searchText: text}, () => {
                   this.state.searchText.length > 1 ? this._getSearchedData() : null
               })}
               value={this.state.searchText}
               placeholder='Search restaurant or cuisine'
    />

    <TouchableOpacity onPress= {() => this.setState({searchText: ''})}>
        <Icon name="md-close-circle" style={{color: 'gray', fontSize: 15,}}/>
    </TouchableOpacity>

</View>
```

Comment: Can you show your _getSearchedData function ?

Comment: what you did seems to be correct . a minimal working example would give more clarity

Comment: You could add `ref={input => { this.textInput = input }}` in `TextInput` then calls `this.textInput.clear()` to clear it. But this works only for Androids ( https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/18278 ). If you want to use for IOS. Please use this module https://github.com/agiletechvn/react-native-text-input-enhance

Comment: it is broken in current RN version , so try plugin https://github.com/nikolaiwarner/react-native-text-input-reset/

Comment: @Prabhu if I keep console.log in _getSearchedData  function, the issue is there.

Comment: @gaback , it is happening in android as well. I've checked in Samsung prime devices. It only works first time. From the 2nd time, it has the same previous issue. And react-native-text-input-enhance  module doesn't solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I've only tested in android devices. Simply unfocusing the textInput solves the problem.

```
<TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({searchText: ''}),
                    Keyboard.dismiss()
                }}>
    <Icon name="md-close-circle" style={{color: 'gray', fontSize: 15,}}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```